# python equivalent of r's ?? to search for a function

Tags: python, ipython

Is there an easy way to search for python functions inside the repl, something like the ?? magic command in R? I'd like to input a function name or substring, and return a list of potential matches.

I've been experimenting with some of the pytorch tutorials, and the versions of the docs have methods that have been moved to other parts of the package. I'd like to be able to search text for the function without having to look in google if possible.

Comment: iPython lets you use tab to autocomplete partial names, and will display a list of all names if there's multiple matches. You can't really "search" with that though.

Comment: Not really, no. R's is quite nice

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this question well, Here is a `python` function `find` which can search any function in a specific module using `pattern` regex .

```
import re
import inspect

def find(pat, module, level = 0):

    def get_funs(pat, module):
        funs = [x for x in dir(module) if inspect.isroutine(getattr(module, x))]
        matched = [x for x in funs if re.findall(pat, x)]
        return {getattr(module, x): module for x in matched}

    def get_modules(module):
        ms = {getattr(module, x): x for x in dir(module) 
        if inspect.ismodule(getattr(module, x)) and not x.startswith('_') 
        and getattr(module, x).__name__.startswith(module.__name__)}
        return ms

    fun_lst = {}
    ms = [module]
    dks = get_modules(module)
    
    while level > 0:
        for m in list(dks):
            dks.update(get_modules(m))
        level -= 1 
    for m in dks:                    
        fun_lst.update(get_funs(pat, m))      
    return [(x.__name__, y.__name__) for (x , y) in fun_lst.items()]
```

You can for example search `one_hot` one hot encoding function in `pytorch` package like this;

```
find('one_hot', torch, 1)

# [('one_hot', 'torch.nn.functional'), ('one_hot', 'torch.onnx.symbolic_opset9')]
```

the number `1` is the level you want to search in, means in the module level `(0)` or sub modules `(1)` or sub-sub-modules `(2)`.

You can also use patterns to get the function;

```
find('.*_hot', torch, 1)    # same result as above
# [('one_hot', 'torch.nn.functional'), ('one_hot', 'torch.onnx.symbolic_opset9')]
```